# phpmyadmin mysql syntax error - multi where conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need help with my query syntax. I am using phpmyadmin 4 and mysql (not sure of version but suspect it is 5.6. My database has a table called places that contains columns `id, city, state, sightings and date`. My website takes input from the user via `$_POST["city"]` and `$_POST["state"]`. I want to increment sightings by 1 where the table entries for city and state match.

Using phpmyadmin's SQL query builder, I tested possible query structures using place names rather than variables. The following query was successful:

```
UPDATE places SET sightings = sightings +1 WHERE city =  "Denver" AND state =  "Colorado"
```

I then clicked "create PHP code" which produced the following:

```
"UPDATE places SET sightings=sightings+1 WHERE city = \"Denver\" AND state = \"Colorado\"";
```

I inserted this code, substituting the place names for variables declared from `$_POST["city"]` and `$_POST["state"]`...

```
$result = cs50::query("UPDATE places SET sightings=sightings+1 WHERE city = \"{$city}\" AND state = \"{$state}\"");
```

and got error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Denver', 'Colorado')'
```

I have tinkered with this line of code for hours and can't get it to work. The fact it works in phpmyadmin means its doable, I am just coding it wrong.

The function query is defined in a custom library provided by the course I am studying, CS50. I wonder whether there is some limitation to the function (can post the code if interested) or am I just using the wrong syntax???

Any help is welcome, apologies if my question is confusing, this is relatively new to me.

Comment: What is \Denver\ in the query what do the " \ " mean. Never saw that before

Comment: not sure, I ran a query in phpmyadmin, it worked so I clicked "create PHP code" and that's what I got, its very confusing!!

Comment: I believe phpMyAdmin added the `\"` to escape the double-quotation marks in the query, because without it PHP will interpret that as the end of the variable.

Comment: hmm, ok but if you add double-quotation marks in a query it becomes a string right? Or am I completely wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
"UPDATE places SET sightings=sightings+1 WHERE city = 'Denver' AND state = 'Colorado'";
```

I've always found that single quotes are more correct than double quotes, even if they are escaped.

Comment: yes I have tried single quotes but around the variables ie `'{city}'`. I am not really sure the curly braces are correct syntax, i'll try it again tho, thanks for your input.....fingers crossed

Comment: I'm not even sure that your syntax for "sightings+1" is correct.  I would think that should be a SELECT because you have to grab the value you are updating.  Have you tried it with out that?